# Facade error in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-facade

I installed a package in Laravel 5.2 named [jonnywilliamson/laragram](https://github.com/jonnywilliamson/laragram)

And put in `config\app.php` a alias and service provider like below :

```
 'providers' => [
    .
    .
    .,
    Illuminate\Translation\TranslationServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Validation\ValidationServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider::class,
    Williamson\Laragram\Laravel\LaragramServiceProvider::class,
 ]


 'aliases' => [
    .
    .
    .,
    'URL' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL::class,
    'Validator' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator::class,
    'View' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\View::class,
    'TG' => Williamson\Laragram\Laravel\LaragramFacade::class,
 ]
```

And in my contoller :

```
 use TG;

 public function test()
 {
  return TG::sendMsg('+989118000000', 'Hello there!');
 }
```

And route:

```
Route::get('test', 'Services\Auth\Controller\v1_0\AuthController@test');
```

I also run the following commands :

```
   composer dumpautoload 
   composer dumpautoload -o 
   php artisan cache:clear 
   php artisan clear-compiled
   php artisan optimize
```

But still shows error like:

```
 RuntimeException in Facade.php line 210:
 A facade root has not been set.
 in Facade.php line 210

 at Facade::__callStatic('sendMsg', array('+989118000217', 'Hello there!')) in User.php line 68
 at LaragramFacade::sendMsg('+989118000217', 'Hello there!') in User.php line 68
 at AuthController->test('fa')
 at call_user_func_array(array(object(AuthController), 'test'), array('lang' => 'fa')) in Controller.php line 80
 at Controller->callAction('test', array('lang' => 'fa')) in ControllerDispatcher.php line 146
 at ControllerDispatcher->call(object(AuthController), object(Route), 'test') in ControllerDispatcher.php line 94
 at ControllerDispatcher->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
```

How can i fix it?

Comment: Can you try using full namespace `use Williamson\Laragram\Laravel\LaragramFacade as TG` instead of alias `TG`

Comment: still same error :(

Comment: please help me friends :( it's very important

Comment: Hey did you update the `config/services.php` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function you are trying to call is called `sendMessage`:

```
return TG::sendMessage('+989118000000', 'Hello there!');
```

You are using `sendMsg`, which is causing the error.

Comment: The documentation (https://github.com/jonnywilliamson/laragram) shows as  `TG::sendMessage`. Looks like docs are out of date. Did you give it go in either case?